# Python Mock error with small change on below code, is there any order requirement for mock.patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

can't figure out why I exchange @mock.patch('mymodule.os') @mock.patch('mymodule.os.path') 's place, the code would raise an Error.

```
#mymodule.py

import os
import os.path

def rm(filename):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        os.remove(filename)


#Test.py

from mymodule import rm

import mock
import unittest

class RmTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('mymodule.os')
    @mock.patch('mymodule.os.path')
    def test_rm(self, mock_os, mock_path):
        # set up the mock
        mock_path.isfile.return_value = False

        rm("any path")

        # test that the remove call was NOT called.
        self.assertFalse(mock_os.remove.called, "Failed to not remove the file if not present.")

        # make the file 'exist'
        mock_path.isfile.return_value = True

        rm("any path")

        mock_os.remove.assert_called_with("any path")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here is the Error info:
    F
    ======================================================================
    FAIL: test_rm (**main**.RmTestCase)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/jim/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
        return func(*args, **keywargs)
      File "/Users/jim/Desktop/unitTest/raise.py", line 27, in test_rm
        mock_os.remove.assert_called_with("any path")
      File "/Users/jim/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 925, in assert_called_with
        raise AssertionError('Expected call: %s\nNot called' % (expected,))
    AssertionError: Expected call: remove('any path')
    Not called

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=1)
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/jim/Desktop/unitTest/raise.py"]
[dir: /Users/jim/Desktop/unitTest]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```